# How to split a single column into multiple column using range (Start-End) values in R?

Tags: r, substring, strsplit

I have a text file with multiple values, however, there is no delimiter to differentiate this when loaded into R. There is a secondary file that defines each of the columns based on a start and end position.

I tried to go through the solutions that already exist but could not get information on the range based delineation for multiple columns

The data looks like:

```
    Column1                                                 
    --------------------------------------------------------
    00000000000102019000000000000000000049491000000000004CAD   
    00000000000102019000000000000000000049491000000000005CAP    
    00000000000102019000000000000000000049491000000000023GSP  
    00000000000102019000000000000000000049491000000000030MUD
```

The field range is defined as:

```
    Field Name   | Start | End 
    --------------------------
     COL1         | 1     | 2
     COL2         | 13    | 17
     COL3         | 18    | 12
     ....
```

I have about 200,000 rows with having 55 columns each based on the range described above.

I am not sure how input multiple ranges to create a new dataframe with all the 55 columns split based on the start and end values.

Could anyone please assist me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try the following code. Note that I made the code according with the data that you mention.

```
    example <- c("00000000000102019000000000000000000049491000000000004CAD","00000000000102019000000000000000000049491000000000004CAD")

    name <- c("COL1","COL2","COL3")
    start <- c(1,13,18)
    end <- c(2,17,22)

    # save the second file for reference
    range_df <- data.frame(Field_name=name,Start=start,End=end)

    # Make a function that splits according the second file
    split_cols <- function(string){
      # Get the `n` rows of the second file for iteration
      n <- nrow(range_df)
      # Declare an empty `data.frame` for save the splitted data
      cols <- data.frame(matrix(NA,1,n))
      for(i in 1:n){
        # Get the range of characters with `substr` function
        # The start and end range is defined in the `range_df`
        # column 2 is the `start` character and columns 3 the `end`
        cols[,i] <- substr(string,range_df[i,2],range_df[i,3])
        # save it in each column of the new data frame named `cols`
      }
      # Return the values of the `splitted` string as data.frame 
      return(cols)
    }

    # In order to apply the function above for each row you can either 
    # use `for` loop or apply function. In this case I used `lapply`
    all_data <- lapply(example,split_cols)


    # `lapply` makes the job done, however is in a `list` form. Yo can 
    # structure the data with do.call function
    final_df <- do.call("rbind",all_data)

    # Finally add the columns names from the secondary df
    names(final_df) <- as.character(range_df[,1])
```

Of course this code can be improved considerably but this can get the job done.

Hope this can help

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you could try:

Given:
1) `raw_data` is your text file
2) `mapping` is your column width table

Apply a function to `mapping` row-wise that extracts the corresponding column from `raw_data`. Output from all rows of `mapping` correspond to each column that you need.

```r
raw_data <- data.frame(str_data = c('00000000000102019000000000000000000049491000000000004CAD', 
                                    '00000000000102019000000000000000000049491000000000005CAP', 
                                    '00000000000102019000000000000000000049491000000000023GSP', 
                                    '00000000000102019000000000000000000049491000000000030MUD'))


mapping = data.frame('columns' = c('COL1', 'COL2', 'COL3'), 
                     'start' = c(1,13,18), 
                     'end' = c(2,17,22))

# Funtion that returns column within start and end indexes
columns = function(x, str_table) {
  col = substr(str_table[,1], x['start'], x['end'])
  return(col)
}

# Apply the function columns to rows in mapping 
tab = data.frame(apply(mapping, MARGIN = 1,columns, raw_data))
colnames(tab) <- mapping$columns
```

Here's the output:

```r
  COL1  COL2  COL3
1   00 02019 00000
2   00 02019 00000
3   00 02019 00000
4   00 02019 00000
```